# How to avoid flickering in popover

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. Run snippet
2. click on popover button.
3. popover appears, drag and drop anywhere on the screen
4. now click twice the popover button.
5. popover appears again on the same location where left earlier.
6. But for a fraction of second flickering happens.
   Is there any way to avoid this flickering, please suggest?

So far I have tried to use this event "show.bs.popover" which fires just before popover appears, looks like something could be done here to avoid this flickering but failed to achieve that.

You can use this link to see the issue or run snippet:

https://jsfiddle.net/girinishantg/w9cgzayj/72/

Need to avoid flickering that happens.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            var gTop = 0;
            var gLeft = 0;

            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
                placement: 'bottom'
            });
            
            $('#notesButton').on('show.bs.popover',
                function () {
               // alert('show.bs.popover');
                });

            $('#notesButton').on('shown.bs.popover',
                function () {
                //alert('shown.bs.popover');
                    var popoverId = $(this).data('bs.popover').tip.id;
                    $('#' + popoverId).css({ top: parseFloat(gTop), left: parseFloat(gLeft) });
 
                    $('#' + popoverId).on('mousedown', function (e) {

                        $(this).addClass('active');

                        var oTop = e.pageY - $('.active').offset().top;
                        var oLeft = e.pageX - $('.active').offset().left;

                        $(this).parents().on('mousemove', function (e) {
                            $('.active').offset({
                                top: e.pageY - oTop,
                                left: e.pageX - oLeft

                            });
                        });

                        $(this).on('mouseup', function () {

                            $(this).removeClass('active');
                            console.log("mouseup");
                            var ID = $('#' + popoverId);
                            gTop = $(this).css("top");
                            gLeft = $(this).css("left");
                            console.log($(this).css("top"));
                            console.log($(this).css("left"));
                            console.log("********************");
                        });
                        return false;
                    });
                });
        });
```

```css
.active {
    z-index: 2;
}
.bs-example{
    margin: 150px 50px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <!--script tags should go in the header -->
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">    
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://popper.js.org/">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="popover-demo mb-2">
        <button id="notesButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"   data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="Default popover">Popover</button>
    </div>
    <p><strong>Note:</strong> Click on the buttons to display/hide the popover.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please refer to [mcve] and include the logic for your issue *in the question*.  Questions are expected to be self-contained.

Answer (score -3):

You can disable popover on click event anywhere on the screen.

```
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
            $('[data-toggle=popover]').each(function () {
                // hide any open popovers when the anywhere else in the body is clicked
                if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
                    $(this).popover('hide');
                }
            });
    });
```